# How can mPdf rotate page in existing file in PHP?

Tags: php, rotation, mpdf

I have PDF in `/some_path/file.pdf`. Using mPdf and PHP I would like to open the file, rotate all pages 90 degrees and save under the same name. How do I do that?

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you can do it directly in PHP.
[PHP: PDF_rotate](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pdf-rotate.php)

Comment: I'd suggest you to add an example code to your answer. It is an *almost* link-only answer which are generaly discouraged since they become irrelevant once the link gets broken.